# I want to set maximum number and restrict having negative number in my Ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

I want to restrict having the negative number when I click on my decrement button, and also want to set a maximum limit when I click on my increment button.

Ionic input min and max are not working.

This is **my.ts** code

```
increment(){
   this.order.qty++;
}

decrement(){
   this.order.qty--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to do simple check like below before incrementing/decrementing.

```
increment(){
   if(this.order.qty <= 10) {
     this.order.qty++;
   }
}

decrement(){
   if(this.order.qty >= 0) {
      this.order.qty--;
   }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thankyou sir, It worked, I just changed if(this.order.qty >= 0) into if(this.order.qty >= 1)

Comment: I'm Gald, I could help! yes, you can set the max quantity as per your requirement!